# How am I to predict and extend data that I have acquired as a 1D vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, machine-learning

Currently I have a 1d vector, which when plotted, gives the blue line in the plot below. Now I want to extend this line based on the data values of vector I already have (as shown by the red line). I am aware that I can use simple machine learning to this problem. But is there an inbuilt MATLAB library functon which can also achieve this?

[image]

What exactly would you call this problem of extending the data? It's not interpolation, and I'm sure extrapolation is not a concept. Do not hesitate to ask any questions that would clarify this problem.

Comment: [Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extrapolation is not a concept"... to me this is exactly [extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrapolation is what you're looking for. Since the final part of the curve you want to estimate is rather linear you can use the linear extrapolation.

Let's say our function is *f(i)=i* for *i=1,...,50*, with some random noise added.

```
signal=(1:50)+rand(1,50);
```

The original signal looks like 
[image]

Now let's say we want to estimate the following 10 samples, that is for *i=51,...,60*. By means of linear extrapolation, we can append these 10 samples by the following loop:

```
for i=51:60
    signal(i)=signal(i-2)+((i-(i-2))/((i-1)-(i-2)))*(signal(i-1)-signal(i-2));
end
```

The original formula has been taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation#Linear_extrapolation), in which *x_star=i*, *x_{k-1}=i-2*, *x_{k}=i-1*, *y(x_star)* is the value we're estimating, *y_{k-1}=signal(i-2)*, *y_{k}=signal(i-1)*. Obviously you should re-adapt such formula with the function you're using. Basically you're using the previous 2 values to evaluate the new value.
Now that these newly estimated 10 samples have been appended, `signal` has the form
[image]